# how to skip an index in a tuple result from a sql query

Tags: java, hibernate

I unfortunately need to use 'native' sql queries for a portion of my project to return tuples from unmapped tables.

I have a bunch of queries which are supposed to return the same number of values per row and then go into a processing method to turn them into objects.

eg:

```
List<Object[]> list = ...;
List<MyBean> beans = ...;

SQLQuery qry1 = session.createSQLQuery(...);
SQLQuery qry2 = session.createSQLQuery(...);
SQLQuery qry3 = session.createSQLQuery(...);

list.addAll(qry1.list());
list.addAll(qry2.list());
list.addAll(qry3.list());

for(Object[] tuple : list)
{
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    bean.setSomething0(tuple[0]);
    bean.setSomething1(tuple[1]);
    bean.setSomething2(tuple[2]);
    bean.setSomething3(tuple[3]);
    beans.add(bean);
}
```

now, my problem is that `qry3` does not have a relevent column to populate the value at the 2nd index of the tuple, but does populate the 3rd index. I need to modify it's query so that it populates the tuple with `null` or `""` somehow.

I've tried `"select a, b, null, d"` and `"select a, b, '', d"` however both of these cause an exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1796)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
```

so how do i tell my query to skip an index in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to cast it to the expected type:

```
select a, b, cast(null as varchar), d
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, just check the length of the tuple array, and don't try to set a parameter that you don't have...

Comment: my example is simplified, that is not an option in the real code.