# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
    27 Dec, 2012 6:38:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet commission threw exception
    org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
        at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getTypeName(Dialect.java:347)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlCreateString(Table.java:419)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateSchemaCreationScript(Configuration.java:930)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:383)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
        at com.core.commission.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
        at com.core.commission.service.BaseCommissionService.saveRules(BaseCommissionService.java:48)
        at com.core.commission.service.BaseCommissionService.processSave(BaseCommissionService.java:22)
        at com.core.web.CommissionServlet.processRequest(CommissionServlet.java:51)
        at com.core.web.CommissionServlet.doPost(CommissionServlet.java:34)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
```

I am getting above error while starting the web server.
 I have used enum mapping with enity class. Something like...

```
@Column(name = "commission_type")
        @Type(type = "com.core.commission.model.FNEnumUserType", parameters = @Parameter(name = "type", value = "com.core.commission.dto.CommissionType"))
        private CommissionType commissionType;
```

What is the issue, do i missed anything in configuration ? Thanks !!

Comment: Are you by any chance using PostgreSQL, and does your schema by any chance contain an XML column somewhere?

Comment: Using PostgreSQL only, but do not have any XML column.

Comment: Okay, well it's not that, then!

Answer (score 8):

What the stack trace tells you is that Hibernate is in the process of initialising itself, and in particular, is executing `Configuration.generateSchemaCreationScript`, which goes through all your mapped tables and generates DDL for them. As part of this, it queries the existing columns and converts them into an internal Hibernate representation. It does this by calling [`ResultSetMetaData::getColumnType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType%28int%29) and then calling [`TypeNames::get`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/dialect/TypeNames.java.html) with the resulting type code. The problem is that `getColumnType` is returning a type code of 1111, which means '[other](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.OTHER)'), and Hibernate doesn't know what to do with that.

Basically, somewhere in one of your tables is a column of a type Hibernate can't handle. If you can work out which column that is, you can start thinking about what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a trace on the db side, place some breakpoints or add some log entries in your application's code to identify what is the query that is generating this error, i.e., that is being executed right before the error occurs.

Once you get the query, try to narrow down the root cause by disassembling the statement into minor chunks and see what kind of column/variable is not supported by the dialect.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it's not related to the dialect after all, but with your query. Check this other question to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015795/how-to-skip-an-index-in-a-tuple-result-from-a-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the error.

1111 is for a `Null` value and in my case that column is mandatory and at any time there will be one value from an enum type. Hence no need to set `1111`, I changed it to `VARCHAR` sql type.

Finally it works.

Comment: I faced this issue when running a query like below: SELECT '' as col1, col2 FROM t1

Comment: It's not only for a Null value, it just means "Other"

Answer (score 1):

in your query i think some of the data type are retrieving as unknown type. pls type cast in to appropriate data type which you are using in your java bean.
if you are using  Postgres as your database. in your java code you can type cast it as  eg: `select column_name :: desired type as \"desired_name\"` 
 eg: `select type_name :: text as \"typeName\"`

if "**::**" this creating any problem pls use **\ \:\ \:**   that is you  are including escape character